# Docker-compose volumes: persistant, but where?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I've been struggling with this for weeks on-and-off now, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. It must be something incredibly simple, because I followed many tutorials to the letter and tried just about every command available.

I try to do something very basic: create one (or more) containers with bind volume(s) so I can edit my code locally. I've stripped down a simple test setup to this:

```
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    ports: 
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - "./data:/var/www/html"
```

I've tried different images, built the above through a Dockerfile and configuring nginx to act as you would want it to (serving php/html from /var/www/html), but that made no difference (and does not seem to be directly related to my problem).

Now, from everything I've seen and read, this should create a directory './data' in the folder where the docker-compose.yml file is. But it doesn't. I know an index.php in ./data won't work in this scenario because nginx isn't configured yet, but still I'd expect the contents of ./data to be available when accessing the container in a terminal.

When I use the terminal in the container (through Docker Desktop) I can browse the files in the container, but there is no link to my local ./data folder. Configuring nginx to serve files from the /var/www/html directory works as expected: the browser window shows whatever is punt in the document root.

Now, the really weird part: the contents of the container's /var/www/html directory seem to be persisent. If I put an index.php in it, use docker-compose down, build, prune, up --build or even removing all containers, images, volumes manually keeps the file in /var/www/html after I build and up the container again. Only a system reboot clears this mysterious phenomenon.

From what I understand, bringing down a container should whipe all changes made in the container's filesystem. Re-upping or rebuilding from the image should give a fresh start, but it doesn't.

As no volume is created where I expect it to be (./data on my local dev machine), but any files I put in /var/www/html of the container seem persistent throughout the whole process, I can only imagine some caching is happening -or- a volume is created somewhere in a place I don't expect (that is cleared after a system reboot).

Both docker cli and Docker Desktop app show no volumes whatsoever:

```
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
```

Inspecting the running container in Docker Desktop says (/var/www/test/data is supposed to be my local directory):

```
Mounts
/VAR/WWW/HTML     /var/www/test/data
```

My questions:

- why is no volume directory ./data created (or used, if I create it manually)?
- why are the contents of /var/www/html in the nginx container kind of persistent (even after downing/clearing/pruning/rebuilding everything)?

I have looked everywhere, but I am looking in the wrong places or using the wrong search terms... I cannot find this problem popping up elsewhere. Could it be my system, my specific setup? Could it be write permissions on a file system level?

Typical workflow:

- create docker-compose.yml file
- run docker-compose build (tried skipping this and running docker-compose up --build)
- run docker-compose up

No errors are shown in the process, and nginx logs tell me the server is up and running all ok.

System/version info:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Linux Mint"
VERSION="21 (Vanessa)
```

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.22, build 3a2c30b
```

```
$ docker-compose --version
Docker Compose version v2.13.0
```

```
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Cloud integration: v1.0.29
 Version:           20.10.22
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.18.9
 Git commit:        3a2c30b
 Built:             Thu Dec 15 22:28:04 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           desktop-linux
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Desktop 4.15.0 (93002)
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.21
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.18.7
  Git commit:       3056208
  Built:            Tue Oct 25 18:00:19 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.10
  GitCommit:        770bd0108c32f3fb5c73ae1264f7e503fe7b2661
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.4
  GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Tried just about everything, including system reboots and creating the scenario over and over. The problem remains. I'v checked a loooot of questions and answers here, but the closest I come to this problem is people trying to mount volumes in the image... That's not what I'm doing, I believe... I work with docker-compose.yml solely (until I get this working).

Comment: To add: I read somewhere that trailing spaces in the volume declaration might be a problem (on Linux specifically), but that doesn't seem to be the issue here.

Comment: Difficult to say: I'd try to use another image (maybe some plain alpine linux) and mount the same directory there - just to see if the files then show up as expected or if the this container shows the same issues as the nginx one. Maybe it's some permissions/user-id issue?

Comment: Where is your `docker-compose.yml` file located? Is it in `/var/www/test`? Because then the output of Docker Desktop would make sense. Are you working with a remote docker daemon or is everything running on your local machine?

Comment: What you can also try is doing `docker inspect nginx` from the terminal and look at the `Mounts` section to find out what mounts are present inside the container.

Comment: @Garuno everything is on a local machine, and indeed, my docker-compose.yml file is in /var/www/test. The volume I'd expect should appear in /var/www/test/data, but like I said... it doesn't.

Comment: @Garuno `docker inspect nginx` shows what - I think - should be: Hostconfig: Bounds: says "/var/www/test/data:/var/www/html:rw"

Comment: @Garuno insepction also says: `"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/var/www/test/data",
                "Destination": "/var/www/html",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],`

Comment: @TmTron tried the official 'nginx' image with the same basic compose file... in a new directory. No ./data directory again. I'll look into the permissions/user-id suggestion, although I followed all install instructions on that as well (several times over).

Comment: @Jeroen I'd try with an image that is not related to nginx at all, to find out if this is related to your docker-setup or to the image: e.g. https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine

Comment: The official [nginx image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) mounts to `/usr/share/nginx/html` . Did you try that?

Comment: @Jeroen that is very strange. The setup looks correct. I don't think testing another image will do anything, but what you can try is to bind mount another location. The best is probably to just create a folder in `/` and try to mount that. Maybe there is something wrong with `/var/www`?

Comment: @TmTron I've tried other images, but the volume problem remains. I have also used a Dockerfile to properly configure nginx to use the /var/www/html directory and in that case my browser shows the index.html or index.php in the container directory as expected. So even when I configure and run nginx as it should, it still won't mount to my local directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> /var/www/test/data is supposed to be my local directory
>
> ```
> Server: Docker Desktop 4.15.0 (93002)
> ```

Docker Desktop runs Docker in a hidden Linux virtual machine.  This is true on all platforms, even native Linux.  This means containers can't necessarily access the entire host filesystem.

On Linux, using Docker Desktop, [only the home directory is shared with the Docker VM by default](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/settings/linux/#file-sharing).  This is one of a couple of settings that will apparently work but have unexpected side effects: from your other descriptions it looks like you are bind-mounting something (the directory contents are being persisted) but it's most likely a directory in the hidden Linux VM.

I'd suggest three main options here:

1. Move your project into your home directory; this is what you've already done in [your other answer](/a/74864111).
2. Add the host's `/var/www` directory under the "File Sharing" tab in the Docker Desktop "Settings" page.
3. Don't use Docker Desktop on native Linux.  Uninstall it and use the standalone Docker Engine instead.  (If you already have it installed you may need to [run](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/linuxfaqs/#context) `docker context use default`.)

Comment: This seems to be correct, marking it as the answer and solution. Don't know for certain if this is in the installation docs, but it should be. I've always been developing on a local Apache installation, so /var/www is the natural place for me to work. Moving to ~/Projects now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

@Garuno you are on to something about the directory! I've copied docker-compose.yml to a new directory in my ~/Projects folder and it now works as expected... the local directory is persisted, and gets mounted after rebuild/re-up... yay!

Works:

```
:~/Projects/test3$ ls -al
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 3 jeroen jeroen 4096 Dec 20 14:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 jeroen jeroen 4096 Dec 20 14:28 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 jeroen jeroen 4096 Dec 20 14:30 data
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jeroen jeroen  111 Dec 20 14:28 docker-compose.yml
```

Does not work:

```
:/var/www/test2$ ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 jeroen jeroen 4096 Dec 20 14:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 9 jeroen jeroen 4096 Dec 20 11:22 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 jeroen jeroen  110 Dec 20 14:15 docker-compose.yml
```

The obvious difference is in some group rights on the current directory and the docker-compose.yml file, but even when I chmod /var/www/test2 exactly the same as the Project directory, the bind volume doesn't work.

It does, however, in `/home/jeroen/Projects/test3` ... the data directory gets created, and files touched locally or via the terminal in the container command line show up as they should.

I'm baffled how this would work, or what goes wrong, but it seems my `/var/www` directory just won't work. For now, I'm just happy I got it to work somehow.

If you have any info that sheds extra light on this, please post it as an answer, I'd gladly mark it as the solution for others that might face the same mystery.

Comment: Btw, also different is number of bytes in docker-compose.yml file but that was just a newline thing... did not make a difference.